# Can anything stronger than union bound be shown for correlated random variables

Tags: probability, inequality

I encountered this problem: Let $X$ be a random variables with support in $[0,1]$, and $x_1, x_2, ...$ be a sequence of i.i.d draws of $X$. Let $S_n = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i = 1}^{n} x_i$. By   Hoeffding bound we have
\begin{align*}
Pr[S_n - EX \geq \delta] \leq e^{-2n\delta^2}
\end{align*}
Let $F_k(\delta)$ be the event $\exists n \geq k, S_n - EX \geq \delta$

Can we bound the probability of $F_k$ other than the trivial union bound
\begin{align*}
Pr[F_k(\delta)] \leq \sum_{n = k}^{\infty} e^{-2n\delta^2}
\end{align*}

Thanks for the answers! Might I ask a more general question for which $\delta$ is not a constant but $\delta_n$. What is a (as small as possible) sequence of $\delta_n$ so that $Pr[F_k(\delta)]$ can be bounded below arbitrary $\epsilon > 0$ for sufficiently large $k$. For example
\begin{align*}
\delta_n = \sqrt{\frac{\log{n}}{n}}
\end{align*}
suffices because 
\begin{align*}
Pr[F_k(\delta)] \leq \sum_{n = k}^{\infty} n^{-2} \leq \frac{1}{k-1}
\end{align*}

Comment: You could probably use a maximal inequality for martingals, but I don't believe that this will give you a stronger result in this setting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can adapt standard reflection argument (while utilizing $S_n-EX\to 0\text{ a.s.}$) to show that
$$P(F_k(\delta))\approx 2P(S_k-EX\ge \delta)$$

---

Here is a good approximation for large $k$ - not an upper bound though. Approximate $tS_t-t\mu$, $t\ge k$ by a Brownian motion $\sigma W'_t$ ($\sigma^2=Var(X)\le \frac 1 4$). Then 
$$S_t-\mu\sim\sigma\frac {W'_t}t\sim \sigma W_{1/t}$$
for $\frac 1 t\le \frac 1 k$ using BM's time inversion ($W$ is another Brownian motion). But then
$$P(\max_{t\ge k}S_t-\mu\ge \delta)\approx P(\max_{t\le 1/k}  \sigma W_t\ge \delta)=2P(W_{1/k}\ge \frac \delta\sigma)= 2P(W_1\ge 2\delta\sqrt k)\approx \frac {e^{-2k\delta^2}}{\delta{\sqrt {2k\pi}}}$$
which is much better than the trivial union bound
$$\frac {e^{-2k\delta^2}}{1-e^{-2\delta^2}}\approx \frac {e^{-2k\delta^2}}{2\delta^2}.$$